# Why are we getting UnsupportedVersionException: The broker does not support INIT_PRODUCER_ID, after Helidon MP 3.2.1 upgrade

Tags: helidon

We are migrating our code base to Helidon MP 3.2.1 and are noticing that our Kafka consumers are throwing this exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: The broker does not support INIT_PRODUCER_ID
```

This seems to be related to a transitive dependency change for Kafka Clients. We are able to get around this issue by specifying *enable.idempotence=false*, for which the default seems to have been changed for that Kafka client.

Question: is this the right way to get passed this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue of new Kafka client with older versions of Kafka broker [KIP-679](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-679%3A+Producer+will+enable+the+strongest+delivery+guarantee+by+default) which enabled backward incompatible client feature by default. Workaround is explicitly disabling producer idempotence with **enable.idempotence: false**

Exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: The broker does not support INIT_PRODUCER_ID
```

Workaround:

```
enable.idempotence: false
```

Messaging connector config example:

```
mp.messaging:
 connector:
   helidon-kafka:
     enable.idempotence: false
     bootstrap.servers: ${oci.test-stream.endpoint}:${oci.test-stream.port}
     ...
```